# How do I automatically enable disabled extension before loading the website on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

RIght now I have [Extension Automation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extension-automation/ghopjgdkodchjclkkfdekhjfomdbakkb?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension that does the job but not quite as I wanted as it automatically enable disabled extension **after** loading the website on chrome.